# How can I solve Anaconda seaborn library issue?

Tags: seaborn, scatter-plot, line-plot, catplot

I am trying to work data visualization. I am using anaconda jupyter lab but always getting the error message.
For example,

```
sns.lineplot(x = "timepoint", y = "signal", data = df);

AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'lineplot'
```

It is same thing with sns.scatterplot and sns.catplot
I am using seaborn==0.10.1. Can you help me?

Comment: Try `!pip install seaborn` or `!conda install seaborn` in an empty cell, and try again

Comment: You might have a local file named seaborn.py